# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

Tags: java, ssl

estoy intentando leer datos de una url , el caso es que tengo el programa perfectamente funcional , conecta y me descarga la respuesta de la petición perfectamente (Siempre que lo ejecute desde mi IDE , que es Netbeans , pero lo he probado con otros IDE´s y también funciona). El problema esta cuando hago el ejecutable JAR del programa. Entonces justo en la linea:

```
connection.connect();
```

Genera el siguiente error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at util.HammerReader.peticion(HammerReader.java:107)
        at com.mycompany.getjavaurlinterfaz.Marco.ejecutarActionPerformed(Marco.java:371)
        at com.mycompany.getjavaurlinterfaz.Marco.access$800(Marco.java:17)
        at com.mycompany.getjavaurlinterfaz.Marco$8.actionPerformed(Marco.java:217)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
```

Lo que no entiendo es porque este error se genera solo cuando ejecuto el executable JAR , en lugar de lanzar el programa desde el IDE.

He leido que añadiendo los protocolos https se arreglaba:

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
```

Pero esto no ha solucionado nada.
A ver si me podéis echar un cable. Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿El jar es ejecutado en otra máquina?.

Comment: No , el JAR lo estoy ejecutando en el mismo equipo donde lo ejecuto con el IDE.

Answer (score -1):

Intenta ejecutando el jar después de modificar las opciones de Java:

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
java -jar miApp.jar
```

Comment: Buenas , lo he intentado pero sigue dando el mismo error. Lo que no me explico es porque al ejecutarlo desde mi IDE no da ese error y desde el JAR si.